# Поиск в файле

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть строки в файле формата:

```
'file:'.$puth.'|msg:'.$str.'|date:'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Есть функция, которая ищет строку формата:

```
'file:'.$puth.'|msg:'.$str.'|date:'.date('Y-m-d');
```

Написал скрипт, но она работает, только когда строки идентичны

Вот сама функция:

```
function checkStr($str,$puth)
{
    // Если нет такой записи $str сегодня, то возвращаем false
    $string = 'file:'.$puth.'|msg:'.$str.'|date:'.date('Y-m-d');
    $data = file(self::fileLog);
    $data = array_map('trim', $data);
    if(array_search($string, $data) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы, функция искала почти такую же строку, только без H:i:s

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkStr($str,$puth)
{
    // Если нет такой записи $str сегодня, то возвращаем false
    $string = 'file:'.$puth.'|msg:'.$str.'|date:'.date('Y-m-d');
    $data = file(self::fileLog);
    $data = array_map('trim', $data);

    $data = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($string){
        return strpos($item, $string);
    });

    return (bool) count($data);
}
```

Comment: Только слово "путь" пишется не "puth", а "path"

И если не поможет `strpos()`, то можно попробовать использовать регулярные выражения